# Why do we need to call jpeg_write_marker() and jpeg_write_header() after jpeg_start_compress() ? [libjpeg]

Tags: image-processing, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

From my understanding, **libjpeg** is a library used to compress the image data. I should be able to write the marker metadata without calling `jpeg_start_compress()` function.

I have 2 questions:

- Why doesn't **libjpeg** allow that?
- If I have a source jpeg file (which is already compressed), how can I just modify the metadata details? Is there any flag which I can set to notify the library that we are dealing with compressed images and we just need to modify the metadata details?

Please help.